# Possible non similar jordan Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Be A an M_6(R) matrix so that A^4-8A^2 +16I = 0. What are the possible Jordan Forms non similar to A?

I tried to solve that, so I arrived in the equation (A-2I)^2*(A+2I)^2 = 0. So this will give me two possibilies of characteristic equation: (x-2)^4*(x+2)^2 = 0 or (x-2)^2*(x+2)^4 = 0. So to the  case 1:
eigenvalue 2 I can have: 2 jordan blocks of size two, or one jordan block of size two and two jordan blocks of size one
eigenvalue -2 I can have: 2 jordan blocks of size one

Case 2. The same thing but switching the eigenvalues.

Am I right?

Comment: You give a polynomial that vanishes the matrix. But is it the minimal polynomial?

Comment: I suppose it is. But it's not explicitly pointed in the question. I think must be the minimal polynomial if it vanishes the matrix? I'm wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're wrong. Any polynomial which is a multiple of the minimal polynomial will also vanish the matrix.